# Verify the monotonically increasing property of this array

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, recurrence-relations

I'm doing some exercises on calculating the Array limiting and I am stucked in verifying a monotonically increasing array. Hope someone can help me with the problem.

For an array,

$x_1=1, x_2=1+\frac{x_1}{x_{1}+1},...,x_n=1+\frac{x_{n-1}}{x_{n-1}+1}$

get the limit of $x_n$ when $n$ increases to infinity.

Known: It is required to use the monotonically increasing property of the array which is hard for me now. Once the property is verified, the limit of the array is obvious.

Thank you!

Comment: Hint: $\,x_n=1+\frac{x_{n-1}}{x_{n-1}+1}=2-\frac{1}{x_{n-1}+1}\,$ then $\,x_{n+1}-x_n=\frac{1}{x_{n-1}+1}-\frac{1}{x_{n}+1}=\dots$

Comment: Thank you dxiv! I think I have got your idea!